# What does this provision mean?

Tags: employment

*The provisions of this Act are in lieu of any right of action, statutory or otherwise, founded on a breach of duty of care or any other cause of action, whether that duty or cause of action is imposed by or arises by reason of law or contract, express of implied, to which an employee, dependant or member of the family of the employee is or may be intitled against the employer of the employee, or against any employer within the scope of this Act, or against any employee, in respect of any death, injury or disability arising out of and in the course of employment and whrere no action in respect of it lies.*

I can not understand this provision completely... I can not imagine this situation. I am not an english-speaker. Help me.

PS. Especially, I don't know the expression 'in lieu of'... In dictionaries, it means 'replace' or sort of.

Answer (score 1):

*in lieu of* means *instead of*.

Basically your only right to take legal action are what the Act gives you - you can't sue for breach of contract, breach of duty of care or anything else.